# Run Configuration Selection in Intellij IDEA new Layout is gone

Tags: intellij-idea

I used to have the run configuation selector in the navigation bar but when switching to the new layout the selector is gone and I can't find a setting to show it.

It used be be in the upper right navigation toolbar:

[image]

How to get the run configuration selector back with the new layout?

IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.4 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-233.14475.28, built on February 13, 2024

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the main toolbar at the top and select the action to customize it:

[image]

In the dialog that opens, select the "Right" area, click `+` to add a new action, search for the "Run Widget" action and click OK to add it:

[image]